# Got an error "Ran out of input" while querying the Chroma HTTP Server

Tags: python-3.x, embedding, langchain, large-language-model, chromadb

I am currently working with customized chatbot.

I have deployed ChromaDB on **AWS EC2**.
And I have embedded about 700K documents into the 'system' collection of ChromaDB. And it is all embedded successfully.
But when I try to query(get relevant documents) from the ChromaDB, I get following error.
"**Ran out of input**".

[Screenshot of error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsDpp.png)

I have used chromadb of **langchain** framework.

If anybody ran into this error and fixed, please drop solutions here.

I wondered if the HTTP server querying isn't working well. So I tried to embed 10-20 documents into another collection in the ChromaDB and requested query. And it worked out.
So I could easily guess that this is due to processing large amounts of documents.

Comment: are you using db retriever, you can have parameter to control the output.
retriever = vectordb.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 2})

Comment: I have tried but it didn't work.

Comment: managed to find the solution? @EagerBeaver